# Understanding the sales fee for NFT erc721 secondary transaction

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am developing a solidity contract to upload Ethereum-based erc721 NFT to opensea.
As a result, there is a way to create a collection in opensea and charge a secondary fee.
Also, I know that there is a way to configure eip-2981 by combining it with erc721.
I am trying to minting using erc721A and minting to buyers through the minting page. Do I have to write a contract with eip-2981 because OpenC is not making a collection? Even after reading articles on the web, I don't quite understand which method to use and why. I wish someone could sort it out.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Your collection will not show up on OS until at least 1 NFT has been minted.  I would recommend testing this out on their test site using the Rinkeby network.  Also to answer your main question, secondary sales goes something like this:

You as the collection owner can choose how much of a fee you would like to charge up to 10%.  You must also know that OS takes 2.5% off the top of any sale regardless as well.  So say someone wanted to sell their NFT for 1 ETH, and the collection royalty was set to 10%.  When that NFT sells, the collection owner would get 0.1 ETH and OS would take 0.025 ETH.  The total royalties collected would be 0.125 and the seller would receive 0.875 ETH.